# Php mysql print row in 3 divs

Tags: php

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
```

Is there any way to print each third database row in a div? So every div gets one row. Like a newsfeed.

I want the first print to be in the fist, second in the second, third in the third, fourth in the first, fifth in the second and so on.

Is this possible? Like skip every third or something. With php

Comment: Add your code whatever you tried... So we are here to give you solution.

Comment: Use for loop or foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code like below. May this helps you.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from table_name");
$k=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($k==1){
        echo '<div id="first"></div>';
    }
    if($k==2){
        echo '<div id="second"></div>';
    }
    if($k==3){
        echo '<div id="third"></div>';
        $k=1;
    }
    $k++;
}
```

OR

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from table_name");
$k=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($k==1){
        $div_id = "
    }
    if($k==2){
        $div_id = "second";
    }
    if($k==3){
        $div_id = "third";
        $k=1;
    }
    echo '<div id="'.$div_id.'"></div>';
    $k++;
}
```